# Smallest non-consecutive number in unsorted array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to write a function that returns the smallest non-consecutive number of an unsorted array. If the whole array is consecutive, the closest number that would extend the array.

```
nextId([1,2,3,4]) returns 5
nextId([1,4,3]) returns 2
```

My try:

```js
   

 function nextId(arr) {
      let sortnum = arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);

      for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {

        if (sortnum[i] + 1 !== sortnum[i + 1]) {
          return sortnum[i] + 1
        } 
else(sortnum[sortnum.length - 1] === sortnum[sortnum.length - 2] + 1) {
          return sortnum[sortnum.length - 1] + 1
        }
      }
}
```

If I outcomment the if or else-statement, they both work perfectly fine on their own, yet they don't work for some reason when I put both of them in one statement.

Comment: Keep in mind [`else`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) won't accept any condition, if you want to add another condition you should use `else if`.

Comment: Also `sortnumb` -> `sortnum`

Comment: was just posting that in the answer. Deleted now, with those two changes it works.

Comment: Note that calling this function will also mutate your array as a side effect, so slice and sort locally if you don't want those side effects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop your array and compare if current element in sorted array is same as `index + 1`. If everything is in order, then just `arr.length + 1` is next missing item.

```js
function nextId(arr) {
  let sortnum = arr.slice().sort((a, b) => a - b);

  for (let i = 1; i <= arr.length; i++) {
    if (i != sortnum[i - 1]) {
        return i;
    }
  }

  return arr.length + 1;
}

console.log(nextId([1,2,3,4]));
console.log(nextId([1,4,3]));
```

Comment: that's a nice extraction of the problem :) But wouldn't it then be good to have a `seed` (like id's start from on 1000 (or from `Math.min( ...arr)`)?

Comment: @Icepickle I don't know. OP does not mention that kind of issue. There is plenty of improvements depending on situation that is outside this issue scope

Comment: I think this should probably rather be `return sortnum[arr.length-1] + 1;`? Otherwise, for `[2,3,4]` you’d get `4`, but it should be `5` instead, I think.

Comment: @CBroe It will return `1`. Because that is missing from beginning of array (at least with my understanding of OP array structure)

Comment: Okay, could be that’s what they actually want, can’t really tell a 100%.

Answer (score 2):

Would have to slice the array to make a copy if that's required, but this will work:

```js
function nextId(arr) {
  return arr.sort().find((v, i, a) => v + 1 != a[i + 1]) + 1;
}

console.log(nextId([1,2,3,4]));
console.log(nextId([1,4,3]));
```

For the case where all the values are subsequent, this works by virtue of the fact that `number + 1 != undefined` will always evaluate to true.